# How do I get all the image files and clean them up?

Tags: media

On my Drupal 8 website I have created multiple media contents and uploaded image file to each content. When I update new image of a media content, the old image file remains unused in the image directory.

How can I query and retrieve all the image files, check if they are used by any media content, if not, delete them from the database and from the image directory?

This is how I have tried. But I did not see any image file that I have uploaded.

```
$files = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::loadMultiple();

foreach ($files as $file) {
   dump($file);
}
```